# Cygwin - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: cygwin

I am using cygwin to rpmBuild a package on windows 7 and it seg faults.

```
buildRpm.sh: line 71:  8156 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) rpmbuild -v -bb --clean SPECS/Myspec.spec
```

the core dump file has the below contents -

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=611097F3
eax=00000000 ebx=00E5668C ecx=00E56688 edx=00000000 esi=FFFFFFFF edi=00000000
ebp=0022A8D8 esp=0022A8D4 program=D:\cygwin\lib\rpm\rpmb.exe, pid 8156, thread main
cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023
```

I tried the `rpmbuild` command on Linux for the same spec file on Linux and it worked.

I have tried `rebaseall`. It did not work.

I then tried:

```
rpmbuild -v -ba --clean SPECS/Myspec.spec
```

and it gave the output:

> error: Bad owner/group: /cygdrive/d/test/SPECS/MySpec.spec